# R Drake - configure make() to not use cache at all

Tags: r, caching, config

- I have complex data ingestion pipeline/scripts but data are really small.
- During development, I throw warnings on places something is fishy/wrong with data.
- I want to continue with the development because these issues may take a
  while to solve.

Yes, there might be other solutions to what I do (record errors to log file, package with tests, ...).
Anyway, I would like to see the warnings on every call of make(), even if the code did not change.

Back to my question: Is there an option in config to not use cache and force make() to run whole plan on every call?

Comment: and yes - I can call clean() before every make(). But that does not answer my question.